# How can I read tuple inputs in multiple line from user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tuples

I want to read below inputs from the console: name and date combination seperated by a comma. For example:

```
Allegan,11-12-2013 
Douglas,29-12-2016 
Junkers,27-03-2017 
Biruinta,10-04-2014 
ABC,27-03-2017
```

Comment: Do you want the input to be in one line, where the pairs are space separated? Could you share please the expected output?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `split(",")`.
Just take input and split it.

```
name, date = input("Enter something: "). split(",")
print("Name: " + name + " and Date:" + date)
```

Input: `Allegan,11-12-2013`

Output: `Name: Allegan and Date:11-12-2013`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your reading a csv file ([Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)) over stdin. If that is the case you could use the csv module like this:

```py
from sys import stdin
import csv

for row in csv.reader(stdin):
    print(row)
```

```py
['Allegan', '11-12-2013']
['Douglas', '29-12-2016']
['Junkers', '27-03-2017']
['Biruinta', '10-04-2014']
['ABC', '27-03-2017']
```